AWS Cloudformation error while creating SNS subscription on loop
Below is my cloudformation snippet that creates a SNS topic along with the subscriptions to the SQS endpoint based on parameters file (paramters.json)
paramters.json
{
  "Key" : "sqlmulValues",
  "Value": "US,europe"
}

cloudformation snippet
Parameters:
  ......
  sqlmulValues: 
    Default: "a,b"
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
Resources:
  NewSNSTopicName:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties:
      TopicName: "my-test-sns"
  # Handling Multiple SQS subscription
  Fn::ForEach::Subs:
    - Args
    - !Ref sqlmulValues
    - 'SqsSubs${Args}':
          Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
          Properties:
              Endpoint: Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${BU}-sqs-${env}-${id}-${Args}"
              Protocol: sqs
              TopicArn: !Ref 'SnsTopic'

Now, i'm looking to modify the Fn::ForEach::Subs: to add the filter policy based on the country name.
If US it should add
FilterPolicy: {
  "country": [
    "US.int"
  ]
}

if Europe,
FilterPolicy: {
  "country": [
    "EU.br"
  ]
}

I came up with
......
sqlmulValues: 
  Default: "a,b"
  Type: CommaDelimitedList
Conditions:
  IsCountry: !Equals [!Select [0, !Split [",", !Ref sqlmulValues]], "US"]

Resources:
  NewSNSTopicName:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties:
      TopicName: "my-test-sns"
  # Handling Multiple SQS subscription
  Fn::ForEach::Subs:
    - Args
    - !Ref sqlmulValues
    - 'SqsSubs${Args}':
          Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
          Properties:
              Endpoint: Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${BU}-sqs-${env}-${id}-${Args}"
              Protocol: sqs
              TopicArn: !Ref 'SnsTopic'
              FilterPolicy:
                community:
                  - Fn::If:
                      - IsCountry
                      - "US.int"
                      - "EU.br"

but it throws,
Transform AWS::LanguageExtensions failed with: Type mismatch for parameter /sqlmulValues on resource IsCountry.IsCountry

Where am I going wrong ?
